# What caching strategy/technology should I use for this php/mysql xml generating api

Tags: php, mysql, xml, caching

I am developing a php/mysql based api that returns generated xml from executing multiple sql queries and then assembling the result sets into a single xml string/document.

I will have multiple clients requesting various flavours of this api for example:

http://domain.com/api//playerbio/12345 would return a  player's biography with various sections such as personal info, current ytd stats, career stats, list of injuries etc.

this type of api request would be made by many clients every hour and for the various leagues, teams, rosters, players etc

The statisticians and editors of the source database are managing this content continuously throughout the day.

I currently have this api reading directly from the editors source database, pretty much guaranteeing that any xml document generated will be up to date.

I am contemplating implementing a caching strategy to reduce the number of times the source database is queried as the average xml document requires 4-7 queries to gather all of the data for assembling.

I am looking for strategies and technologies here especially considering that this api will be called 300-500k times a day and the xml document size ranges from 20k to 100k.

I know there's APC, memcache, memcached, Redis, MongoDB and even creating a simple file based cache but I would like to hear from others what they have used in similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of memcached - its fast, easy to use and has standard libraries for integration.

memcached is extremely fast and can serve up lots of data, but it is not persistent, its a true cache, so expect to have a way to load data.  The auto-trimming of old keys is priceless.

Answer (score 0):

If you want blazing fast & persistent data, Redis is the way to go else MemcacheD will be your alternative minus the persistence but if your application runs on a single server then APC would be ideal.